# Cannot run GMMHMM (Hidden Markov Model with Gaussain Mixture emissions in hmmlearn) with high number of mixtures

Tags: hidden-markov-models, mixture-model, hmmlearn

I'm trying to use `Gaussian Mixture Model` within the hmmlearn package using the following configuration for a time series with 49792 samples:

```
model = GMMHMM(n_components=40, n_mix = 5, tol = 1e-6, covariance_type = "full", n_iter=100, verbose=True)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: n_samples=3 should be >= n_clusters=5

I cannot comprehend why n_samples = 3 because of which the error is being thrown (It seems during the initial random `clustering`, the number of samples in some clusters become very less). Is there any way to get around this problem?